# Most natural way to prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+2}$ diverges

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I don't know **how** my teacher wants me to prove that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+2}$$

diverges. All I know is that I have to use the $a_n>b_n$ criteria and prove that $b_n$ diverges.

I tried this:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+2} = 
\frac{1}{1+2}+\frac{1}{2+2}+\frac{1}{3+2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n+2} = \left(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}\right) = \left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\right)-\frac{3}{2}$$

but I can't get a relationship between $a_n$ and $b_n$ of these series.

If I go to the root of the comparsion criterion, I know that:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+2} = 
\frac{1}{1+2}+\frac{1}{2+2}+\frac{1}{3+2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n+2} = \left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}\right)+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}> \frac{2}{4}+\frac{4}{8}+\cdots+g_n$$ for some $g_n$ that I'm lazy to calculate.

Therefore, by the properties of limits, since the righthand sum $p_n$ diverges, the lefthand sum $s_n$ diverges too, because $s_n>p_n$.  But I don't know if my teacher would accept that, I think she would only accept that I use the argument for the $a_n$ of the sum, not for the partial sum.

I also thought about rewriting:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+2} = \sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$$

but I don't see how it helps because the indexes are different.

All I need is an argument that will work with the $a_n$ of the $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$, in relation with $b_n$ from $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$

Comment: Compare with $\sum \frac{1}{n + 2n}$

Comment: For large enough $n$, $\frac{1}{2n} < \frac{1}{n+2}$.

Comment: Is it fair in your context to use the fact that $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges, or would you need to prove that fact?

Comment: I think the title is not too good; the most *natural* way, IMO, is one which is not allowed by the constraints: recognize the series as differing from the harmonic series in finitely many places.

Comment: @AustinMohr I should ise it as a fact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n+2} = 
\sum_{n=3}^{N+2} \frac{1}{n}
$$
So your series differs just by finite many terms from the harmonic series, which diverges.

Answer (score 1):

You can do in this way:

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+2} $ converges, say $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+2} = S$.

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}=1+\frac12+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+2}=\frac 32+S$,

Which will contradics with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$ diverges.

Comment: But I can't prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n}$ diverges using the comparsion criterion :(

Comment: ok I see your edit

Comment: why $\sum\frac{1}{n}$ divergence implies $\sum\frac{1}{n+1}$ divergence?

Answer (score 1):

When you're only trying to distinguish between convergence and divergence, you can toss around big numbers pretty freely:

$$
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+2} \geq \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{1000n} = \frac{1}{1000}\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}
$$

The righthand sum diverges ("dividing infinity by 1000 leaves you with infinity"), which implies the lefthand sum diverges ("it is even larger than infinity").

Please note that I do not advocate literally treating infinity as a number, but the statements I use in quotes are useful so far as they go, and probably rigorous statements of them appear in your text.

Answer (score 1):

For all $n$, $n + 2 \leq n + 2n$, so

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3n} \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n + 2},
$$

and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3n}$ diverges since it is a constant multiple of a divergent series.